# Need objects of inheriting classes to be visible before classes are defined

Tags: c++, inheritance

Usually you would declare and define the base class and then do the same for the inheriting class before declaring objects of the inheriting class. Unfortunately for for visibility reasons I need to declare the objects before the inheriting class is defines (although after the base class is defined).

I though that I could make a forward declaration for the inheriting class but if I do it like this:

```
class BaseClass
{
    //content
};

class InheritingClass;
```

It does not recognise that it is inheriting but If i do it like this.

```
class BaseClass
{
    //content
};

class InheritingClass: public BaseClass;
```

The compiler expects me to finish the definition. Is it possible to make the situation I am describing work?

Comment: Please provide a more complete example. How exactly do you need to use the `InheritingClass`?

Comment: You can still forward-declare an inheriting class without providing the base-specifier-list. But you can only declare pointers to those objects.

Comment: If the first code block is not enough, then the significant fact you want to know is that it was derived from the base class.  Sounds like a job for base class pointer.

Comment: Why do you need to declare the inheriting class? How is it used?

For "visibility reasons" do you mean you would like to hide something? May be the compiler firewall pattern is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in a compiler.  You can declare another class identical to base, and use it for type checking, and then derive from that when you actually define it.  Presumably this will be a subcategory of your base class that you are looking for.  However, it won't be the exact type.  If you're not looking to partition the hierarchy, then I still think the base class is what you should be using, since that is what you are looking for.

```
class base {int unused;};
class base_specific : public base {};

class actual : public base_specific {
public:
    actual (int i) : m(i) {}
    int m;
};

int main(){
    actual x(4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forward declarations are not definitions. Therefore `class InheritingClass: public BaseClass;` doesn't make any sense. You can however make forward declarations and then later define it:

```
class base;
class derived;

// ...

class base {};
class derived : public base {};
```